# Python: Multi variable nonlinear fitting like matlabs nlinfit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I used to use Matlab to perform nonlinear fits using the `nlinfit` function.
This allowed me to create a fit for a vector of observed responses to two predictors.
Let's for arguments sake say Cu recovery through a separation process based on the feed grade and feed rate. When using Matlabs `nlinfit()`, the function accepted the `Rec` column of data as the observed response, and then a n by 2 matrix of predictors, in this case feed rate and feed grade.

I have now switched to using Python (NumPy, SciPy and MatPlotLib) instead of Matlab and cannot make the minimize function perform the same multiple variable nonlinear regression fitting.
I have managed fine with a single predictor variable with many observations, but not a multiple variable predictor set.

Comment: could you post some code?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried thus far? Matlab's `nlinfit` function uses the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm so you could try `scipy.optimize.leastsq` or `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` (looks like Matlab has a "robust" option).